# Jquery validation engine message not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using the following code to pump a message to JQuery validation engine:

`$(".ref2").validationEngine("showPrompt", "Please enter your references if you can", "error");`

The issue is odd, when you submit the form with incorrect references, the error message is shown, closing the message and trying to resubmit appears to do nothing, the form doesn't submit and the error message doesn't show up.

I've investigated and the error message IS being created, the div element exists but you just can't see it? Am I wrong in thinking you can just resend a prompt?

Comment: Replicate issue where it can be checked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error turned out to be that the Validation engine was being called twice in quick succession. What this did in this specific case was to set the Z index of the validation message to -50.

I believe this to be quirk of the poorly formed javascript that was being used on the page at the time, as each successive call decremented the Z index by 25. So it was being hidden behind a label.

Removing the second call fixed the problem, and moving away to FluentValidation fixed my sanity.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13445711)

Comment: @TheRickest - I think it is good you posted this as an answer. Please edit it and better explain why it was a problem for future viewers

Comment: @teovankot - This does explain why it didn't work for him. He asked the question and then when he found out the problem he posted an answer on it. See comment I left for him

Comment: @GiladGreen I'll try to explain, I realised this was still open and wanted to give it at least something to help anyone with the same issue.

Comment: @TheRickest - I understand and I think it was good that you did so. I'm just saying that maybe you can include more explanation of why it was a problem or so

Comment: I've given as much info as i have, it wasn't the validation engine going wrong but the incorrect usage of it causing bugs.